Indexed pages not visible in Google search console
I have recently started a blog page and initially a lot of pages were not indexed, but then I decided to go and manually request indexing for my new webpages through Google search console. After a day I inspected the URL and they all got indexed, but they are still not reflected in the overview page.
It says I have 7 indexed pages and 5 non-indexed pages.
Problem 1: When I singularly inspect the URLs that say non-indexed, they say they are indexed.
Problem 2: I have a total of 16 webpages on my site, but 7+5=12 so, why are the remaining 4 webpages not being recognized?
Can someone tell me how to fix this issue?

When the Google search console shows the URL is on Google means this page was cached and indexed. Sometimes indexed pages do not show on Google search due to lack of authority. Try to link from the page and add a few internal links, also update the title & meta then resubmit to indexing. After that share this page with social media pages, so this page earns few external backlinks.
Wait a few days and check it, soon it will be indexed & showing on Google SERP.
